# Diode-connected PMOS

Tags: mosfet, analog, pmos, circuits

Im currently a year 1 electrical engineering student. May I ask, for a diode-connected PMOS (gate connected to drain), why is |Vsd| = |Vgd| ?

Comment: Are asking why you take the absolute value or why they are equal to each other? Please explain what you don't understand the equation that you have provided? **_ALSO_** please quote where you saw this equation because it is likely that the location where you got this equation will also provide you some information about the equation.

Comment: The equation is not correct. If the gate and drain are shorted together, then \$V_{gd}\$ is zero. But \$V_{gs}\$ will be approximately equal to \$V_{th}\$ (if there's non-zero current through the channel).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The relation you have asked for in the question is wrong.

In the diode connected PMOS, fig.B, Gate and Drain are shorted. 
Hence \$V_G = V_D\$.

And therefore \$V_{GD} = 0 \$ and \$V_{GS} = V_{DS}\$.

M2 will always be in saturation as \$ V_{DS} > V_{GS} - V_{Th} \$ always.